# How does one access `$global` or `out.global` in non-top-level components in MarkoJS?

Tags: javascript, marko

I'm trying to access global variables from a Marko component, but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: out is not defined`.

```
class {
    onClick(event) {
        console.log(out.global.message)
        event.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

Shouldn't `out.global`/`$global` be accessible everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` is made available to components in certain lifecycle methods -- `onCreate(input, out)`, `onInput(input, out)`, and `onRender(out)`. In one of those, assign the value you'd like to `this` in order to make it accessible elsewhere in the class:

```
class {
    onCreate(input, out) {
        this.message = out.global.message
    }

    onClick(event) {
        console.log(this.message)
        event.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

---

For non-top-level components, state and properties are not automatically serialized, so the above code would cause `this.message` to be set in the component on the server, but that property would be undefined on the client.

To make `out.global.message` available on the client to non-top-level components, you have to change the render function to specify that it should be serialized, as in [the docs on server-side rendering](https://markojs.com/docs/server-side-rendering/#serializing-globals):

```
template.render({
    $global: {
        serializedGlobals: {
            message: true
        }
    }
}, res);
```

Comment: And what if I don't want my global variable to be serialized (e.g., if my variable is function), and I need to use this global function in non-top-level component?